# Gmail SMTP works in SpringBoot but not on Tomee Server

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, gmail, imap, tomee-8

I am using exactly the same settings for javax Mail session, which works like charm in SpringBoot App but fails in Tomee Server.

On SpringBoot's application.properties, I have the following settings (which works):

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=<my gmail>
spring.mail.password=<App PW generated on Google>
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

And here are the setting in Tomee's conf/tomee.xml settings

```
<Resource id="mail/bjm" type="javax.mail.Session">
        mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
        mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
        mail.smtp.port=587
        mail.transport.protocol=smtp
        mail.smtp.auth=true
        mail.smtp.user=<my gmail>
        password=<App PW generated on Google>
    </Resource>
```

On Tomee, when I run the application, I get the following error message:

```
 failure (javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: null)
```

I am puzzled what wrong am I doing in tomee.xml because I have followed the guidelines from here: https://tomee.apache.org/master/docs/configuring-javamail.html

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: mail.smtp.auth=true  <--- isnt that for use with xoauth2?

Comment: @DalmTo, As mentioned in the post, I just followed the instructions from official Tomme documentation. Link also specified above.

Answer (score 0):

The sample you "state" you are following [Declaring a JavaMail Resource](https://tomee.apache.org/master/docs/configuring-javamail.html) which you aren't really since you have changed it.

Is for use with `MAP SASL XOAUTH2 mechanism configuration`  Xoauth2 is a form of oauth2 that is supported by [googles imap server](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol).

rather then following the sample you have changed it to use user name and an apps password. This is not Xoauth2.

Offending lines of code:

```
spring.mail.username=<my gmail>
spring.mail.password=<App PW generated on Google>
```

You are getting a fail for `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException` because you have not added a valid access token as shown in the sample, which you have not shown in your code.

```
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "<username>@gmail.com", "<YourAccesToken>");
```

To be 100% clear an [apps password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) is not an access token an [access token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2) must be created by standard Oauth2 mechanizes of requesting authorization of the user, with a mail scope.